# IOException stops application although the exception was handled

Tags: java

Sometimes when I open a stream:

```
stream = url.openStream();
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: 
    Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://...
```

and my applications ends although I'm handling the exception with:

```
catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

could someone please explain to me why the catch block wasn't entering although it's an IOEcxeption?

thx

Edit (additional code ;-)

```
private String request(URL url) {

    InputStream stream = null;
    String line, response = new String();

    try {
        stream = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader buffReader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null)
            response += line;

    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HTTPException httpexc) {
        httpexc.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

I run this code very often in my application and just sometimes I get the mentioned exception.

Here's a part of the stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: ...
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you show us how you handled it ? including the try block . :)

Comment: Can you post the entire code ?

Comment: Most likely it was caught somewhere else.  e.g. in another thread, or a nested block.

Comment: Unless you post your full code and complete error stack trace it is difficult. You may catch the super class `Exception` and see.

Comment: Is this your real code? There's something strange with your finally clause...

Comment: what' strange about it?

Comment: Not only the finally clause. Why is the 'InputStream stream' an attribute? Within the finally close the BufferedReader instead the stream!

Comment: @vhunsicker - it makes no difference in this case whether you close the input stream or the buffered reader.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, you are right. For me the code didn't look clean (to store the stream into an attribute)..

Comment: so what would you recommend to do instead?

Comment: something like: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your exception handling.  If an exception is thrown in the `openStream()` call, then the `finally` block will attempt to call `close()` on a `null` reference, and you will get an NPE.

That could explain the behaviour you are seeing:

1. The `openStream()` fails.
2. The `catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace();}` prints the stack trace.
3. The `finally` block throws an NPE, causing `request()` to terminate abnormally.
4. If the `request()` call is running on some thread with no "uncaught exception handler", then the thread could die silently due to the NPE.